# AOSP layout xml file preview in eclipse

Tags: android, android-source

I imported the entire AOSP project into Eclipse by following the instructions at [here](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.sg/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html). I can build and run the project properly. But during my working, there are two problems still confuse me.

1. I can't preview the layout xml files at "/frameworks/core/res/res/layout/". When I open a xml layout file in the graphical layout view. I got some errors like:

> No resources match the configuration
>
> ,,Locale Language__Region__, Left To Right, sw800dp, w1280dp,
>   h800dp, Extra Large Screen, Not Round screen, Landscape Orientation,
>   Normal, Day time, Medium Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft
>   keyboard, No keyboard, Hidden navigation, No navigation, Screen
>   resolution 1280x800, API Level 18
>
> Change the configuration or create:
>   res/layout-ldltr-sw800dp-w1280dp-h800dp-xlarge-notround-land-notnight-mdpi-finger-keyssoft-nokeys-navhidden-nonav-1280x800-v18/mw_decor.xml
>
> You can also click the "Create New..." item in the configuration
>   dropdown menu above.

And the preview is blank. So far I have to run a build every time I changed the xml content and update the device to see the result. This is really inefficient. I hope there's a way to preview the UI just like what we do when developing the normal Android app.

2. When I open a java file in Eclipse, e.g. ActivityManagerService.java. I got a lot of compile errors which are the lines reference the "com.android.internal.R" or some other constants. [image][image]

I just wondering is there any way to get rid of these errors? Because these are really confusing and it's hard to find the real error line in the file.

Hope anybody can give me some hints or instructions. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By some deep searching again, I found two topics same with my problem. They just gave some explanations (no solutions).

1. [Using ADT Layout Editor with Android platform source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/android-platform/layout$20xml/android-platform/q62wn04YPGk/hwuDfTf2t4cJ)
2. [How to include com.android.internal.R into android.jar](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/android-platform/com.android.internal.R/android-platform/Qbg1N5nX0xc/5DdsmESF3TgJ)

But I still think building the entire platform only to check if a widget is in the right place is a great drain of time, and it sounds reasonable that ADT's layout editor should work. I'll appreciate if someone has better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Because it uses android.internals which you cannot access using stock sdk images from Google. Also try searching on how to use android.internals.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I searched how to use com.android.internal.R but the results seems all relative to the app development. But I'm working on the AOSP project. I tried to add the project "/out/target/common/R/com/android/internal" into .classpath file, but didn't work.

Comment: Are you compiling the whole AOSP framework BTW?
If so use this guide

http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/getting-started-building-android-from-source

Comment: Well... I'm not trying to build framework in Eclipse, I know I should use the android build system. And my building is OK. I just feel uncomfortable when I see a lot of errors in my eclipse, so I just wondering is there any way to remove them, :) Anyway, thanks for reply.